# Summary of sufficient conditions for convergence of Fourier series

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis, limits-and-convergence

I would like to summarize various sufficient conditions for various modes of convergence of Fourier series. The followings are what I have gathered so far:

1. **$L^p$ convergence:**

- if $f \in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ for some $1 < p < \infty$, then its Fourier series converges in $L^p$ to $f$

2. **Almost everywhere convergence:**

- if $f \in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ for some $p > 1$, then its Fourier series converges almost everywhere to $f$ (**Carleson-Hunt theorem**)

3. **Pointwise convergence:**

- if $f$ has a bounded variation, then its Fourier series converges pointwise to $\frac{1}{2}[f(x+) + f(x-)]$ at every $x \in \mathbb{T}$

4. **Uniform convergence:**

- if $f$ has a bounded variation and is continuous, then its Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$
- if $f$ is $\alpha$-Holder continuous of order $\alpha > 0$, then its Fourier series converges uniformly to $f$

5. **Absolute convergence:**

- if $f$ is absolutely continuous and $f' \in L^p(\mathbb{T})$ for some $p > 1$, then its Fourier series converges absolutely and uniformly to $f$
- if $f$ has a bounded variation and is $\alpha$-Holder continuous of order $\alpha > 0$, then its Fourier series converges absolutely and uniformly to $f$
- if $f$ is $\alpha$-Holder continuous of order $\alpha > 1/2$, then its Fourier series converges absolutely and uniformly to $f$

*Remark:* A uniformly convergent Fourier series may not converge absolutely. In fact, there exists an absolutely continuous function whose Fourier series fails to converge absolutely.

**Questions:**

1. Did I misstate any sufficient condition?
2. Is there any sufficient condition to add in the above list?
3. What about $L^1$-convergence, convergence in probability and weak convergence?

Comment: Dini criterion https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1109758/proof-of-the-dirichlet-dini-criterion-for-pointwise-convergence-of-fourier-serie

Comment: You may find Saccone's article of interest https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-99-05361-7

Answer (score -2):

Consider the following analytic function represented by the Taylor series
$$
F(z;α,c)=∑_{n=1}^\infty \frac{e^{i c n\!\log\!n}}{n^{\alpha+\frac{1}{2}}}  z^n
$$
**Theorem**.
For $\alpha,c>0$, the function $F(z;\alpha,c)$ is analytic on the open unit disc $|z|<1$ and continuous on the closed unit disc $|z|\le 1$. The series defining the function is absolutely convergent for $\alpha >{1\over 2}$ but not for $0<\alpha\le {1\over 2}$.

The proof of this theorem can be found in the first volume of monograph on trigonometric series by A. Zygmund,  (*Trigonometric series*, Second Edition, Volumes I & II combined, Cambridge Mathematical Library, [MR0933759](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0933759), [Zbl 0628.42001](https://zbmath.org/0628.42001), pp. 197 – 222.).

Comment: This appears to be a transcription of an interesting example which is unfortunately not relevant to the question that was asked. Could you explain why you chose this example in your answer?